# When we talk about colour, can we say 'it is in pink'?

Tags: word-usage

When we talk about colour, can we say 'it is in pink'? 
"In' in the sentences is necessary? OR it has different meaning?

Comment: When you are talking about the colors something comes ***in***,you can say, “Does it come in pink?” ( Is pink one of the colors available)  But if you’re talking about what color that apple is, it is ***not*** “This apple is in red”

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can speak about colors that way, but only in certain contexts, where a verb plus *in* would be relevant to the object being described. For example, we’re familiar with the idea of letters being set *in a font*, so an expression like the following sounds natural:

**Joe:**  What did you think of the code editor?

**Moe:**  I liked it. The keywords were in pink, and the globals in a kind of dark teal. Not your usual scheme at all.

Other verbs that you can use include *painted*, *illuminated*, *dressed* and so on, and they don’t have to be present explicitly so long as the reader can infer their presence.

**Coach (to players):** We’ll do a scrimmage. Yesterday’s starters in black. Everyone else in pink.

**Travel reporter:** They did one of those French *light and sound* things. Greek buildings in blue. Romans in red. Anything after the 1300’s they just left black.